# Writing bits inside hexadecimal array

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm sorry if the title is misleading, but I really couldn't think of a better one.

I have this array here:

```
unsigned int container[] = {0xAAAAAABB, 0xBBBBCCCC, 0xCCDDDDDD};
```

and I have this value:

```
0x444555
```

and I have this position (bits):

```
24
```

Now, the position 24 would point to where the first B is. I need to make this function:

```
void write_bits(unsigned int container[], int index, unsigned int value)
```

that with the parameters I gave previously, would change the array to this:

```
unsigned int container[] = {0xAAAAAA44, 0x4555CCCC, 0xCCDDDDDD};
```

What I have tried first was to manipulate the bits with shift operations so that I could clear up the space for the value to be inserted:

```
void write_bits(unsigned int container[], int index, unsigned int value) {
    int size_of_value = 24;

    int shift_first = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - index;
    int shift_second = size_of_value - shift_first;

    int cont_idx = index / (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT);

    vector[cont_idx] = vector[cont_idx] >> shift_first;
    vector[cont_idx] = vector[cont_idx] << shift_first;
    vector[cont_idx+1] = vector[cont_idx+1] << shift_second;
    vector[cont_idx+1] = vector[cont_idx+1] >> shift_second;

}
```

With the parameters given previously, this will give me:

```
container[] = {0xAAAAAA00, 0x0000CCCC, 0xCCDDDDDD};
```

The problem is that if I use the position 0 or 4, it won't work. Also, I can't wrap my head around inserting the 0x444555 in where the 0s are.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit awkward following your logic, but after clearing the least significant bits in the first element and clearing the most significant bits in the next to make way for the bits you wish to set, all you need to do is *shift and OR* your replacement bits to replace the bits you just cleared.

For example, using your logic (with a slight change in variable names to make it clear whether you are operating on the *least* or *most* significant bits in an element), you could do the following:

```
void write_bits (unsigned *a, int off, unsigned v)
{
    int elembits = (int)(sizeof *a) * CHAR_BIT, /* bits per element */
        lsbits = elembits - off,                /* lsb bits in current */
        msbits = off - lsbits,                  /* msb bits in next */
        cont_idx = off / (sizeof *a * CHAR_BIT);/* current index */

    a[cont_idx] = a[cont_idx] >> lsbits;        /* clear lsits in current */
    a[cont_idx] = a[cont_idx] << lsbits;
    a[cont_idx] |= (v >> msbits);               /* set lsbits in current */

    cont_idx++; /* advance to next element */

    a[cont_idx] = a[cont_idx] << msbits;        /* clear msbits in current */
    a[cont_idx] = a[cont_idx] >> msbits;
    a[cont_idx] |= ((v >> lsbits) << msbits);   /* set msbits in current */
}
```

(**note:** you need to look carefully at your logic for determining `cont_idx` and test whether the number of bits you are replacing will span more than `sizeof (unsigned)` bytes effecting more than two elements, or whether the bits to be replaced all fall within a single element -- that is left to you)

Putting that in a short example using your test case, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void write_bits (unsigned *a, int off, unsigned v)
{
    int elembits = (int)(sizeof *a) * CHAR_BIT, /* bits per element */
        lsbits = elembits - off,                /* lsb bits in current */
        msbits = off - lsbits,                  /* msb bits in next */
        cont_idx = off / (sizeof *a * CHAR_BIT);/* current index */

    a[cont_idx] = a[cont_idx] >> lsbits;        /* clear lsits in current */
    a[cont_idx] = a[cont_idx] << lsbits;
    a[cont_idx] |= (v >> msbits);               /* set lsbits in current */

    cont_idx++; /* advance to next element */

    a[cont_idx] = a[cont_idx] << msbits;        /* clear msbits in current */
    a[cont_idx] = a[cont_idx] >> msbits;
    a[cont_idx] |= ((v >> lsbits) << msbits);   /* set msbits in current */
}

int main (void) {

    unsigned container[] = {0xAAAAAABB, 0xBBBBCCCC, 0xCCDDDDDD},
        n = sizeof container / sizeof *container,
        v = 0x444555;

    write_bits (container, 24, v);

    fputs ("unsigned container[] = {", stdout);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (i ? ", 0x%08X" : "0x%08X", container[i]);
    puts ("};");
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arr-write-bits
unsigned container[] = {0xAAAAAA44, 0x4555CCCC, 0xCCDDDDDD};
```

Comment: Didn't work for any other positions, for example `write_bits(container, 0, v);`

Comment: Of course not -- that is why I left the entire paragraph beginning with "(**note:** you need to look carefully at your logic for determining `cont_idx`..." because the logic above was limited to the case where the bits being replaced spanned element 1 and element 2 of the array.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing is to be clear about the types and sizes of things you are using

- your array appears to contain 32 bit values, so you'd be better using `uint32_t` to make that clear (and more portable).
- the value you are inserting is 24 bits (ie *not* 32 bits), so you need to make that clear too, probably with an additional `size` argument.
- You appear to be using big-endian bit numbering (bit 0 is the most significant bit), which is fine, but you probably want to make that clear.

So your routine becomes:

```
void write_bits(uint32_t container[], unisgned offset, uint32_t value, unsigned size) {
    unsigned idx = offset/32;  // where in container to start writing
    unsigned bits = -offset % 32U;  // number of bits left to write at that position
    if (size <= bits) {
        // fits entirely within one word;
        unsigned shift = bits - size;  // how many bits up to shift value
        uint32_t mask = (UINT32_C(1) << bits) - (UINT32_C(1) << shift);
        container[idx] &= ~mask;    // clear the bits we're overwriting
        container[idx] |= value << shift;   // and write them
    } else {
        // writing into two words
        // first word...
        unsigned shift = size - bits;  // how many bits to shift down for first word
        uint32_t mask = (UINT32_C(1) << bits) - 1;
        container[idx] &= ~mask;    // clear the bits we're overwriting
        container[idx] |= value >> shift;   // and write them
        // second word...
        ++idx;
        shift = 32 - shift;
        mask = ~UINT32_C(0) << shift;
        container[idx] &= ~mask;    // clear the bits we're overwriting
        container[idx] |= value << shift;   // and write them
    }
}
```

This is more verbose than it needs to be -- you can fold common subexpressions together to make it more efficient (or let the compiler's optimizer do it for you).

Comment: @drizer: fixed the obvious typos from transcription.  Should work now.